# perfect singleton design pattern

Tags: c++, singleton

recently I faced an question, design perfect single tone pattern.
I have designed by using one static instance and one static function returns that instance as below.

```
ST* ST::instance = NULL;
ST* ST::getInstance()
{
    mutex.lock();

    if(!instance)
       instance  = new ST();

    mutex.lock();

    return instance ;
}
```

The he asked me to write without using mutex (write perfect singleton without using any synchronization mechanism), then I have changed as below.

```
ST* ST::instance = new ST();
ST* ST::getInstance()
{
    return instance ;
}
```

Is it a perfect design ?? what does he mean of perfect design of single tone pattern ???
What might be his expectation of design ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the visibility of ST::instance?

Comment: Only *he* can answer what *his* idea of a perfect singleton is. Maybe he was looking for this `Singleton& Singleton::instance() { static Singleton s; return s; }`. C++11 guarantees that construction is thread safe. Or it could be it was a trick question since *perfect singleton* is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect singleton. In fact, it's open to some question whether there's any singleton that's worth anything at all.

That said, in C++ the Meyers Singleton is usually the one that's least problematic. The core of it looks roughly like this:

```
static T &get_instance() { 
    static T t;
    return t;
}
```

So the basic idea is to define a single instance of the target type as a static, local to a static member function. That static member function returns a reference to that object. All `singleton`'s constructors are private, so only member functions can use them to create (or destroy) objects of that class. In effect, this means only the one static member function can ever create an instance, and it only creates the one static instance, so all use is of that one instance.

Of course, if you want to badly enough, you can return a pointer instead of a reference, but that's rarely a good idea (probably *not* a good candidate for "perfect").